# $K[X,Y]$ is a PID and a primary ideal in it is not power of a maximal ideal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> I wonder if $M$ is a maximal ideal, $Q$ is an ideal of $R$ and $\sqrt{Q}=M$ then $Q$ is an $M$-primary ideal.

The converse is not true (I know that). We also have that if $R$ is PID which is not field then the set of all primary ideals (maximal ideals) of $R$ is $\{0\}$ and $Rp^{n}$ with $p$ irreducible. It means that the primary ideals in PID are $\{0\}$ and powers of maximal ideals. But I see the example that is if $K$ is a field, take $(X,Y^{2})$ in $K[X,Y]$. It is an $M=RX+RY$-primary ideal of $R$, but it is not a power of maximal ideal (specifically $Rp^{n}$). I see it is contraction because $K[X,Y]$ is a PID and the primary ideal in it is not form of maximal ideal ? Can you explain it?

Comment: K[X] is a PID but K[X,Y] is not. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain#Properties

Comment: In your question you mention an ideal of K[X,Y] which is not principal. It is weird that you also say that this ring is a PID!

Comment: I forget about it. My bad, thank you I got it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if $Q$ is an ideal and $\sqrt{Q}$ is maximal then $Q$ is primary. This is proposition 4.2 in Atiyah and MacDonald.

Answer (score 2):

> Theorem: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Then $R [X]$ is PID if and only if $R$ is a field.

Clearly, $X $ is not unite in $R [X]$, for every commutative ring. Thus,  the above Theorem shows that $R [X,Y]=R [X][Y]$ is not a PID, for any commutative ring with identity.